# Obrigar a preencher input em php

Tags: php

Criei uma tabela com 2 `input type radio`, onde um recebe o `value="Ok"` e o outro o `value="Não Ok"` e logo à frente uma coluna de observação.

```
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td> <textarea type="text" class= "Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';
```

Os `inputs type radio` são de preenchimento obrigatório. Agora pretendia sempre que o `input type radio` recebesse o `value="Não Ok"`, obrigasse o preenchimento do `input` da observação, mas só obrigar nessa situação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer utilizando JavaScript (com JQuery), alterando o valor do atributo required do textarea.

No PHP é preciso colocar uma classe na `td` do textarea (Daria para fazer sem, mas fica melhor utilizando uma classe, caso você coloque outra td entre essas duas futuramente).

```
<?php
    $tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Ok" required></td>';
    $tabela1 .= '<td style="float:center"> <input type="radio" name= "Sim['.$y.']" value="Não Ok" required></td>';
    $tabela1 .= '<td class="obs"> <textarea type="text" class= "Observacao" name="Observacao['.$y.']" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea></td>';
?>
```

No JavaScript basta pegar o click do input e verificar o seu valor, alterando o textarea como necessário:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "Não Ok"){
            $(this).parent().siblings('td.obs').children('textarea').attr('required', 'true');
        }else{
            $(this).parent().siblings('td.obs').children('textarea').removeAttr("required");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: desta forma está a obrigar preencher o `input observacao` tanto preencha o radio `Ok` ou `Não Ok`

Comment: Cara, você pode verificar no console do navegador o javascript e colocar um breakpoint para verificar se o valor do campo (`$(this).val()`) está vindo corretamente e se ele está entrando no `if` certo. Caso esteja tudo certo troque `.attr('required', 'false')` por `.removeAttr( "required" )` no else.

Answer (score 1):

O metodo de validação do formulário via Back-End é mais eficiente do que o Front-End, apesar do ideal é serem Utilizados os dois métodos.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que uma solução simples em PHP seria algo assim:

```
<input type="radio" name="opcao" value="Ok">
<input type="radio" name="opcao" value="Não Ok">
<textarea type="text" name="observacao"></textarea>

if(empty($_POST['opcao']) && empty($_POST['observacao'])){

    echo "<script>alert('Escolha uma opção ou preencha a Observação.');</script>";

}elseif(!empty($_POST['opcao']) || !empty($_POST['observacao'])){

    echo "<script>alert('Ok!');</script>";
}
```